# how to parse a rui file(created by Bosch Rexroth 6000 sofeware) to a dynamic resistance curve?

Tags: xml, matplotlib, math, matlab-figure

I got a .rui file, and it is supposed to contain some information that enable me to draw a dynamic resistance curve.
now I get the original data from that gui file, it's actually a xml file. And I also know how the final dynamic resistance curve looks like. But I can't draw the final curve with xml file.
There are 20 elements that contains curve-like data, I draw them one by one and compare it with the final dynamic resistance curve, but none of them match it.
the curve-like data is below, and the final dynamic resistance curve is https://photos.app.goo.gl/XrJ89QGgR7Zu7Jo97 (the red one).
Any help will be appreciated.

update:
I am using python, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from xml.dom import minidom
doc =  minidom.parse(".../...rui")
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
for i in doc.getElementsByTagName("OBJECTS_DATA")[0].getElementsByTagName("OBJECT")[1:]:
    data_number = i.getAttribute("NUMBER")
    data_1 = i.getElementsByTagName("DATA_SET1")[0].firstChild.data
    data_2 = i.getElementsByTagName("DATA_SET2")[0].firstChild.data
    data_1_list = [int(i) for i in data_1.split('|')]
    data_2_list = [int(i) for i in data_2.split('|')]
    if np.sum(data_1_list) <20 or np.sum(data_2_list) <20:
        continue
    plt.plot(data_1_list, label="number=%s_%s" %(data_number, 1))
    plt.plot(data_1_list, label="number=%s_%s" %(data_number, 1))
# plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

the reason that select matlab and matplotlib is that I think this looks like more a math problem rather than a coding problem. So I guess those who use matlab would help.

```
<OBJECT NUMBER="1310">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>7|77|169|212|232|237|239|245|244|240|244|250|247|244|250|249|246|251|249|241|240|245|243|242|245|240|234|239|242|237|240|242|236|234|240|239|237|242|240|233|236|242|238|238|240|236|232|238|237|232|230|237|235|235|239|235|229|233|236|232|234|237|231|227|231|228|225|230|228|221|224|230|227|227|229|226|222|229|231|227|231|233|229|229|234|232|231|237|235|230|235|240|236|233|239|239|238|243|243|236</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>3|49|117|153|173|184|192|202|206|205|209|215|216|215|221|223|223|229|230|226|226|231|230|231|234|231|227|230|233|230|232|234|231|229|233|232|230|234|233|228|230|234|232|232|234|231|228|233|233|229|228|232|231|231|234|232|228|231|233|231|233|235|233|231|235|234|232|234|233|229|230|233|232|232|234|231|227|231|232|229|231|233|229|229|232|231|229|232|231|227|229|233|230|227|230|230|228|232|232|227</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1311">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|12|99|186|221|234|233|232|237|235|228|228|232|227|222|227|227|224|230|230|223|222|230|229|229|233|228|222|228|232|228|231|234|230|227|234|234|233|238|238|232|235|243|242|243|247|243|239|247|249|245|248|252|247|246|252|250|242|247|252|249</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>114|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|9|67|138|175|195|205|212|223|228|228|232|238|238|236|241|243|242|247|248|244|243|249|249|249|252|250|245|248|252|249|250|253|250|247|251|250|248|251|251|246|246|251|250|250|252|249|245|250|252|248|250|253|249|248|252|251|245|248|252|249</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1312">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>251|255|249|245|251|251|248|253|252|244|246|253|251|250|253|248|242|250|252|247|249|252|246|244|251|248|245|251|249|242|245|251|246|242|246|245|242|248|248|240|240|249|247|246|248|243|238|243|247|242|244|247|241|239|244|242|238|243|242|235|237|243|240|233|238|238|235|240|239|232|230|238|237|236|239|235|228|233|237|232|234|237|231|228|233|232|229|233|232|225|227|233|230|223|227|228|225|230|230|223</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>251|254|251|247|252|252|250|254|254|248|248|254|253|252|255|251|246|251|254|251|252|254|251|249|253|252|250|254|253|248|249|254|252|248|251|251|248|253|253|248|247|254|253|252|255|252|247|251|254|251|252|255|251|249|253|253|250|254|254|249|250|255|252|248|251|252|250|253|254|249|247|253|253|252|255|252|247|251|254|251|252|255|252|249|253|253|250|254|254|249|249|254|253|248|251|252|250|253|254|249</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1313">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>221|228|228|226|229|226|219|223|228|224|224|228|223|219|224|223|220|225|224|217|218|225|223|221|223|220|214|220|223|216|213|220|220|219|223|219|212|215|221|217|218|221|217|212|218|218|215|218|219|212|212|218|217|215|219|215|210|215|217|213|214|218|213|211|215|214|208|210|215|212|213|216|213|209|212|213|211|214|215|209|208|214|213|212|214|212|206|210|213|210|211|214|210|208|212|210|208|212|212|206</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>247|253|253|252|255|253|248|250|254|251|252|255|252|249|253|252|250|254|254|249|248|254|254|252|254|252|248|251|254|250|247|251|252|251|254|252|247|249|253|251|252|255|252|248|252|253|250|253|254|249|248|253|253|252|254|252|248|251|254|251|251|254|252|250|253|252|248|248|252|250|251|254|252|248|251|252|250|253|254|249|248|253|253|251|254|252|248|250|253|251|251|254|252|249|253|253|250|253|253|249</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1314">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>207|212|210|204|209|210|206|210|212|206|203|210|210|208|211|209|203|206|211|207|208|211|207|204|209|208|205|209|208|202|202|209|207|201|205|206|202|207|209|203|200|206|206|205|208|205|199|202|207|203|204|207|204|201|205|205|202|205|205|199|199|206|204|202|205|202|197|201|205|200|196|203|203|202|205|203|196|198|204|201|201|205|202|197|201|202|199|202|202|195|195|203|203|200|203|200|194|199|203|198</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>249|253|252|248|250|252|249|252|254|249|247|252|253|252|254|252|248|250|253|251|251|254|252|249|253|253|250|253|253|249|249|253|252|248|250|251|249|252|254|250|247|252|253|251|254|253|248|249|253|251|251|254|252|249|252|253|250|253|254|249|248|253|253|251|253|252|248|251|253|250|247|251|252|250|254|253|248|249|253|251|251|254|252|249|252|253|250|252|253|249|247|253|253|252|253|252|248|250|253|251</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1315">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>193|200|201|199|202|201|195|196|202|198|199|203|200|195|199|200|197|200|201|195|193|201|200|198|201|199|193|196|201|197|197|201|198|194|199|198|192|192|198|197|197|201|199|193|196|198|195|198|200|194|192|198|199|197|199|197|192|194|199|196|196|200|196|192|197|197|194|197|198|192|192|198|197|191|195|196|193|196|198|194|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>247|251|252|251|253|253|248|248|253|251|251|254|253|249|251|253|250|253|254|250|248|253|253|251|254|252|248|250|253|251|251|254|252|249|252|252|248|247|252|251|250|254|252|248|251|253|250|252|254|250|247|252|253|251|253|252|248|249|253|251|251|254|252|249|252|253|250|252|253|250|248|253|252|248|250|252|249|252|254|250|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1316">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1317">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1318">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1319">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1320">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>133|254|211|194|183|181|182|178|177|184|186|183|184|190|187|185|188|184|181|184|189|183|182|184|180|181|186|185|181|183|183|179|181|186|181|181|184|180|179|184|185|180|180|181|178|180|185|181|178|182|186|182|181|183|178|179|184|184|179|181|181|176|177|181|177|175|178|175|174|179|181|176|176|177|174|176|182|179|176|179|179|176|179|182|177|178|181|179|178|183|184|178|180|185|183|182|186|182|180|185</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1321">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|15|175|255|212|193|182|181|183|178|176|180|182|179|179|185|184|182|186|183|180|184|190|184|183|185|181|182|189|189|183|185|186|182|184|190|186|185|189|187|185|191|195|188|188|190|188|189|196|193|189|192|193|189|191|196|191|190|197|198|193|194</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1322">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>195|189|191|197|194|192|195|192|189|194|198|192|191|193|189|190|197|195|190|192|193|188|190|195|190|189|193|190|188|193|195|189|189|195|192|191|195|191|189|193|198|191|189|191|187|188|195|193|187|190|191|186|188|193|188|187|190|187|185|190|192|186|185|191|190|187|190|187|184|188|193|188|185|187|183|184|190|190|183|185|186|182|184|188|184|182|186|183|181|185|188|182|181|187|186|183|186|183|180|184</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1323">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>189|184|181|184|180|180|186|187|180|182|183|178|180|185|181|180|183|180|177|182|186|180|177|180|177|178|183|182|177|179|185|182|179|181|177|177|182|184|178|179|181|176|177|182|179|177|180|178|175|179|183|178|176|178|175|175|181|180|175|177|179|174|175|179|176|174|179|182|177|178|179|175|175|180|179|176|179|176|173|177|182|176|174|177|174|174|179|179|174|175|177|173|174|178|174|173|176|175|172|176</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1324">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>178|173|172|177|177|174|177|176|172|175|180|176|173|175|173|172|177|178|173|174|176|171|172|176|174|171|175|173|170|174|177|172|171|176|176|173|176|174|171|173|179|175|172|175|171|170|175|177|172|173|174|170|171|175|173|170|173|172|169|173|177|171|170|173|170|169|175|174|170|171|177|174|171|174|170|169|174|177|171|172|174|169|169|174|172|170|172|171|169|173|177|172|169|171|169|169|174|174|169|170</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1325">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>176|174|171|173|170|169|173|176|171|171|173|169|168|173|172|169|172|171|168|170|175|171|168|171|168|168|172|173|169|169|172|168|168|172|169|167|171|176|171|170|173|168|168|172|173|169|171|170|167|170|175|171|168|170|168|167|171|173|168|169|171|167|167|171|169|167|170|169|166|169|173|169|167|171|172|169|171|170|167|169|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1326">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1327">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1328">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
        <OBJECT NUMBER="1329">
            <NUMBER_OF_DATA>216</NUMBER_OF_DATA>
            <DATA_SET1>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET1>
            <DATA_SET2>0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0</DATA_SET2>
        </OBJECT>
```

Comment: Show us your code please. Also, you chose tags from 2 different programming languages. Which one are you using?

Comment: Looks like a plotting problem.  Lots of languages can solve it, including Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have more work to do:

1. This isn't valid XML.  I don't see a root tag.
2. Parse the XML somehow.  I don't know what Matlab has to help.
3. Each object has an id and two data sets of varying lengths.  I'd create an object of some kind, calling it something other than Object, to encapsulate them together.
4. I don't know what DATASET1 and DATASET2 are.  Hopefully they aren't x and y.  You need to take the data value out of each one and split them by the | token into numbers.

Once you do all that you'll have a collection of data that you should be able to plot.  Good luck.

Comment: 1. The original file is too long, I only pasted the curve-like data here.
2. the reason that select matlab and matplotlib is that I think this looks like more a math problem rather than a coding problem. So I guess those who use matlab would help.
3. How to do that exactly?
4. Neither of them is x, because they are not from 0 to max of them, they all looks like y.